# Kafka - producer - handle "failed to send"

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm running a 0.8 Kafka, and build a producer using the provided Java API.
The API functions of sending a message (or messages) return void.

Is there a way to get the status of the sent message? If it sent or failed?

This is extremely important to us since we are reading the messages from a file and we want to delete the file after all messages were sent. But if there were errors and some messages weren't sent and I delete the file it will cause a loss of a very important data.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe an exception is thrown if sending didn't succeed? So in case you catch that exception you wouldn't delete your files.

Comment: The "Send" function is aSync (return immediately while the actual sending is happens later by different thread.) so there is no exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your producer to wait until it gets n acks from the Kafka cluster (request.required.acks) so that you have some kind of guarantee that the data has been committed properly before deleting your source file.

If *really* you need to be sure that the message sent succeeded, you might want to consider the alternative of making the producer to be synchronous (producer.type=sync). This way, you would be able to catch any exception thrown by the blocking invocation and act accordingly. The exception thrown by send() is kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException.

Kafka's Java API is not ideal, hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeap, I left it there and get back to it lately and you are right. The `type=sync` is the only way of ensure the message was sent but that decrees the performance like hell.
We are looking for a different queues at the moment.